# Nagios and Cherokee

Tags: nagios, cherokee

I just changed from apache2 to cherokee, I am running nagios, but I can't seem to figure out how I can get the cherokee to make the nagios webinterface show up.

Has anyone done this before  and can someone point me in the right direction ?

I have tried the documentation of cherokee but it only mentions a proxy running apache2.

Running Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [cherokee cookbook](http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_nagios.html)

This is and advanced method only namely. In reality, it is exactly as simple.

In this case, the relevant information from the configuration file is limited to a couple of snippets:

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
```

and

```
Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
```

Please note the above paths are the ones used in the Nagios Quickstart guide. The paths are bound to change if you used any prepackaged release.

We will translate these directly into a pair of directory-type rules.

The first one will match the /nagios/cgi-bin directory, and will be handled by the CGI handler. We will map the /usr/local/nagios/sbin as the Web Directory for the rule, in the Rule tab.

Comment: A little less conversation.